# How to make cp report an error when file was not copied?

Tags: cp

I am using `cp` command with `-n` option meaning if the target file exists it should not be overwritten, in short -- file is not copied.

The thing is, if I run cp and all files are copied, its exit code is 0 (OK), and when some files are not copied it is still 0 (OK).

How to make cp report an error, or signal in some other way the fact the files were not copied -- in short allow me to differentiate between those runs (as described above)?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you can do that with CP, because it only tells you if the command ran sucessfully or not. I would use **rsync** instead

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512571/rsync-keep-in-textfile-failed-tranfers

Comment: Correct, the cp command does not provide info if a copy of a file was successful or not. Using a for loop the exit code of each iteration can be checked.